# Mule expression language MEL vs MVEL - Same thing?

Tags: mule

I have a query around the Mule Expression Lanaguage(MEL). Is MEL the same as MVEL? Or just a wrapper around MVEL with some added mule functions etc.? Or something else completely?

I can see that there is a an older MVEL evaluator and can see that the two are similar. But I wan to know the details and whether all MVEL expressions are supported by MEL etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Mule in Action 2nd edition](http://www.manning.com/dossot2/)

> The Mule Expression Language, a.k.a. MEL, is based on the MVFLEX
>   Expression Language (MVEL), which gives access to a complete range of
>   programmatic features, enriched with Mule-specific variables and
>   functions.